# How to plot histogram from the R output?

Tags: r, histogram

I am trying to plot histogram from the R output which is not a data frame. Below are my codes and the output.

```
x <- replicate(1000, 
               {y <- rpois(200, 1)
               {lambda0 <- 1
for(i in 1:1) 
  {
  if( i == 1 ) cat( sprintf("%15s %15s %15s %15s\n", "LogL", "Score", "Information", "New Estimate"))
  logL        <- sum((-lambda0) + y*(log(lambda0)))
  score       <- sum((y/lambda0)-1)
  information <- sum(y/(lambda0)^2)
  lambda1      <- lambda0 + score/information
  cat( sprintf("%15.4f %15.4f %15.4f %15.5f\n", logL, score, information, lambda1))
  lambda0 <- lambda1
}  
} 
               })
```

Below is my output

[image]

I'm trying to take the new estimate from the output and create histogram. Can you please help?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to store the value for New Estimate during your loop. This way you can retrieve your results after the loop is finished.

Comment: Can you please help me retrieving it? I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Normally when using a loop, you specify a variable in advance in which you can save the result for each iteration. E.g.: 
`numbers <- 1:3`

`result <- list(length = length(numbers)`

`for (i in seq_along(numbers){
 result[[i]] <- numbers[[i]] + 1
}` In this example there is a vector of three numbers, you want to add one to each number and save the result. You can do this by creating a list of length 3 (adding length is better, but not necessary) and for each "i"th iteration, you save the result in the "i"th element of the list.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this and let u know

Comment: I have posted my suggestion as an answer to your question. If this works, please mark it as the correct answer. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the value for New Estimate during your loop. This way you can retrieve your results after the loop is finished. Normally when using a loop, you specify a variable in advance in which you can save the result for each iteration. E.g.:

`numbers <- 1:3`

`result <- list(length = length(numbers)`

`for (i in seq_along(numbers){`

`result[[i]] <- numbers[[i]] + 1`

`}`

In this example there is a vector of three numbers, you want to add one to each number and save the result. You can do this by creating a list of length 3 (adding length is better, but not necessary) and for each `i`th iteration, you save the result in the `i`th element of the list.

After finishing the loop you can retrieve the results from the `result` variable. And you can retrieve the `i`th result by using square brackets: `result[[i]]`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution...I'm struggling to how to use the above method for my codes mentioned above. I don't know how to change my codes accordingly. If u can help me it would be great

Comment: Could you explain to me what you are trying to do, step by step.

Comment: Hi, i have tried the above code and got the output..Thank you